# Spring data redis java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, jedis

I am using spring 5.0.5.RELEASE with spring-data-redis 2.0.6.RELEASE with redis-clients 2.9.0 but I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
```

If I downgrade the version of sping-data-redis to < 2.0 then this problem fixes but then I get following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.<init>
```

Does anyone know which versions of spring-data-redis and spring framework are compatible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> Spring Data Redis 2.x binaries require JDK level 8.0 and above and
>   Spring Framework 5.0.7.RELEASE and above.

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#requirements)

Answer (score 1):

importing

```
org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

class instead of importing

```
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

resolves this error for me.